# Distance of points along circumference of circle from origin after translation of the circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Imagine I have a unit-radius circle centered at the origin.  Every point on the circumference of the circle is one unit from the origin.

Now imagine I translate this circle, let's say +0.5 along the y-axis.

Every point on the circumference of the circle is now a distance between 0.5 and 1.5 from the origin.

What is the function whose domain is 0-360$^\circ$ (angles around the circumference) and whose range is 0.5-1.5 that maps points on the circumference to distances from the origin?

Comment: Use typical equations to translate from polar to cartesian coordinates to get the point in terms of x, y, z, ... Then use Pythagorean's theorem to find the distance to the origin, substituting y for y+0.5. The function you're looking for is a composition of these steps.

Comment: @Joseph_Kopp wait, but i don't have polar coordinates for any of these points after translation (aside from the points on the y-axis).

Comment: @abcd You have $x = \cos \theta, y = 0.5 + \sin \theta$ and the squared distance to the origin is $x^2 + y^2 = \ldots$

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the input angle is measured at the origin, not the circle centre. Then such distance function would describe the circle in polar coordinates. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Draw. A. Picture.

Comment: @peterwhy no i mean angles measured around circle center

Comment: @abcd Thanks for the confirmation, otherwise I would have answered (incorrectly) $$r(\theta) = 0.5\sin\theta + \sqrt{1-0.25\cos^2\theta}$$.

Answer (score 0):

@dxiv gave the correct answer first in the comments:

For any point on the circumference, we have x = cos $\theta$ and y = 0.5 + sin $\theta$.

The distance to the origin is always $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.